# How to connect wsdl soap webservice and handle datas

Tags: android, erp, ksoap

I am developing mobile sales application on android which is worked integrated to ours erp configuration. I need help. First time I use ksoap and I'm in trouble with.

We developed an erp configuration with 1C:Enterprise and I write webservice on 1C:Enterprise. 1C provide webservices as soap, wsdl file. I'll share my android app code and wsdl file.

Firstly here is the my erp web service wsdl file :

[image]

Here is class which is defined connection parameters:

```
public class Connection{
public static String Url ="http://localhost/BAS/ws/MobileTech.1cws";
public static String Soap_Action = "http://localhost/BAS/ws/MobileTech.1cws?wsdl/GetMobileUsers";
public static String Method_Name = "GetMobileUsers";
public static String Namespace   = "http://localhost/BAS/ws/MobileTech.1cws?wsdl";  
private static Connection instance = null;  
private Connection()
{       
}

public static Connection getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Connection();
    }
    return instance;
}}
```

And here is I did request to webservice with ksoap2(I want to explain,this codes in doInBackground in the class what is extends AsyncTask :

```
Connection conn = Connection.getInstance();
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(conn.Namespace,conn.Method_Name);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpse = new HttpTransportSE(conn.Url);
    ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("Administrator:17870505".getBytes())));
    try 
    {
        httpse.call(conn.Soap_Action, envelope, headerList);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.e("x", response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("hata :", e.toString());}
    return filled;
}
```

and I got these exceptions :

> 10-09 14:32:27.300: E/x(2666): MobileTech.db oluşturuluyor
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): Process: com.example.mobiletech, PID: 2666
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at com.mobiletech.db.ServiceGetDatas.doInBackground(ServiceGetDatas.java:21)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at com.mobiletech.db.ServiceGetDatas.doInBackground(ServiceGetDatas.java:1)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     ... 4 more
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mobiletech-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     ... 8 more
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):         ... 9 more
>   10-09 14:32:27.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2666):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

I couldn't solve this? Could you help me, where is my mistake?

and I want to add, I added Intenet permission to AndroidManifest file.

Comment: are u sure u add ksoap properly as It says  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject" on

Comment: yes I'm sure and I checked after I got exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added ksoap2 library in your project, and use this code that was tested in ksoap2 v2.4, this answer is not your answer, only I try to explain you how works this. Please test and make sure that library exists

Create the class WebService:

```
package com.test.myapp;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class WebService {

    public static String invokeWS(String VAR_METHOD_1, String VAR_METHOD_2) {
        String resTxt;
        String webMethName = "YOUR_METHOD_NAME";
        // Create request
        String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo FIRST_PARAMETER = new PropertyInfo();
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo SECOND_PARAMETER = new PropertyInfo();

        // Set Name
        FIRST_PARAMETER.setName("NAME_1");
        // Set Value
        FIRST_PARAMETER.setValue(VAR_METHOD_1);
        // Set dataType
        FIRST_PARAMETER.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object

        // Set Name
        SECOND_PARAMETER.setName("NAME_2");
//      // Set Value
        SECOND_PARAMETER.setValue(VAR_METHOD_2);
//      // Set dataType
        SECOND_PARAMETER.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(FIRST_PARAMETER);
        request.addProperty(SECOND_PARAMETER);

        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        String URL = "YOUR_URL_WEBSERVICE";
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            // Invole web service
            String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION +webMethName, envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to fahren static variable
            resTxt = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resTxt = "Error occured";
        } 

        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

And in your doInBackground use this for return string result:

```
return WebService.invokeWS(VAR_1,VAR_2);
```

Comment: Let me ask you one thing. This erp system provide soap web service but we can see just wsdl file and we can request just to wsdl file? How can I do that? because probably it's this exceptions reason.